# How can I create a XML file with vb.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I need to create a XML file that stores the routes of all the files that my program copies.

I'm trying to use the same code I have to create a log.

```
Public Sub XMLRoutes(ByVal routeAs String)
    Dim xmlPath As String = "C:\Log\"

    'Create route if it doesn't exist
    If Directory.Exists(xmlPath) = False Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(xmlPath)
    End If

    Dim xmlSW As System.IO.StreamWriter

    Dim Path As String = "C:\Log\CopiedRoutes.xml"

    If File.Exists(Path) = False Then
        Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(Path)
    End If

    xmlSW.WriteLine("<route>" + route + "</route>")
    xmlSW.Flush()
    xmlSW.Close()

End Sub
```

But I don't know if it will work properly, and I don't know how to place the starting tags

I'd like my result to end up like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<parameters>
  <route>route 1</route>
  <route>route 2</route>
  ...
</parameters>
```

Comment: IMHO, look into [**serialization of objects/classes to XML**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315703/how-to-serialize-an-object-to-xml-by-using-visual-basic-net-or-visual), you will find out this is easy to work with than what you are currently doing.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ page not found....

Answer (score 0):

Using XElement and XML literals makes this easy, IMHO.

```
''' <summary>
''' adds route to xml file
''' </summary>
''' <param name="route"></param>
''' <param name="pathToXML">the route xml file, will be created if does not exist</param>
Public Sub XMLRoutes(pathToXML As String, route As String)
    Dim xe As XElement
    If Not IO.File.Exists(pathToXML) Then
        'create the file
        xe = <ROUTES></ROUTES>
        xe.Save(pathToXML)
    Else
        xe = XElement.Load(pathToXML)
    End If
    Dim newRoute As XElement = <route><%= route %></route>

    xe.Add(newRoute)
    xe.Save(pathToXML)
End Sub
```

To use it

```
    Dim path As String = "C:\Log\CopiedRoutes.xml"
    XMLRoutes(path, "one")
    XMLRoutes(path, "two")
```